# Sum of infinite series with variable range between -1 to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $S$ denote the infinite sum $2 + 5x + 9x^2 + 14x^3 + 20x^4 + ....$, where   $| x | < 1$, then what is the value of $S$?

I am not able to find the generalized form. What is the trick to solve it?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

The coefficients seem to be
$$a_n=\frac{n(n+3)}2$$ So
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n} \,x^{n-1}=\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n(n+3)} \,x^{n-1}$$
Now, use 
$$n(n+3)=n(n-1)+4n$$ and recognize the derivatives of ... something

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$S=2+5x+9x^2+14x^3+20x^4+\cdots$$

$$(1-x)S=2+(5-2)x+(9-5)x^2+(14-9)x^3+(20-14)x^4+\cdots$$

Let $T=(1-x)S$

$$T(1-x)=2+(3-2)x+(4-3)x^2+(5-4)x^4+\cdots=1+\dfrac1{1-x}$$ for $|x|<1$